# File upload in angularjs with code igniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, ng-file-upload

What I am trying to do is to **upload excel file** using angular and codeigniter .
But the problem is when I am am uploading it is not been accepted by the CI function ,Status code is 200 when I am sending but I am getting empty array when I am printing

> print_r($_POST);   print_r($_FILES);

**Here is my service:**

```
function UploadExcel(file,uploadUrl) {
     var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
```

Here is my directive

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is my Controller

```
 $scope.ImportApplicant = function() {
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    var uploadUrl = 'user/fileUpload';
    UserService.UploadExcel(file, uploadUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular code

```
$scope.setFile1 = function(element)
{
    $scope.currentFile = element.files[0];
    var t = element.files[0].name;
    var vali = t.split('.'); 
    var length = vali.length-1;
    var final = vali[length];
    if(final=='txt' || final=='pdf' || final=='doc' || final=='docs')
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event)
        {
            $scope.missing.image = event.target.result
            $scope.$apply();
            $("#image_show").show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Codeigniter

```
$base64_string=$data['profile_image'];
    if (preg_match('/base64/i', $base64_string)) 
    {
    $randomfile=time().'.jpeg';
    $filename='./uploads/users/'.$randomfile;
    $this->Cashback_model->base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $filename);
    }
    else {
            $file_name = explode('/', $base64_string);
            foreach ($file_name as $keyval) {
               $randomfile = $keyval;
            }
        }
```

model

```
public  function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string,$output_file) {
             $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb");
            $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

            fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
            fclose($ifp); 

            return $output_file;
        }
```